Using multiple struct types with identical members?
I guess this is not possible with C at all. But I have to ask to make sure.
I have two structs which have identical members which I want to sort the list for.
struct a 
{
tm seconds;
struct a *next;
/* further stuff */
};

struct b
{
tm seconds;
struct b *next;
/* further, but different stuff as in a */
};

I am looking for a possibility to have only a single function to sort this type of concatenated list.
Something like
sort(void struct *locallist)
{
/* do sort for locallist->seconds */
return;
}

It should be generic for both types of structures as the different content is not at all a concern as long I can sort based on the "*seconds".
Any ideas?
/KNEBB

The singular list contains both types...somehow?

This sounds like an "XY question". Wouldn't you rather have a list of the same struct type but with a member which points out data parts that might be different from node to node?

You might find this other question interesting.

a and b  here as seen as nodes in linked lists and you want to sort all nodes of the two lists? What will be the output of this? in_place sorting would not work, since  the seconds field are common but the rest is not. It is easy to sort them using a single compare function returning an array of pointers to these nodes, but is it ok for you? What is the expected output of the sort process?

Actually, that's perfectly possible in C (almost anything is possible in C), but if you're thinking about something more "higher-level", like subclassing, that's not the way to go.

I think you may want something like what I discuss/show in my answer: Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C

Thanks for comments& ideas. For clarification: I have indeed two seperated lists and they will stay separated. I will not mix those two structures. I just want to have only a single function to sort these liste independend of their data.

@CraigEstey And that's "subclassing C style"! Your "virtual callback table" variants are really nice. But, again, may be too complicated for this specific case. I would advise Christian to go with Lundin's proposal (ordering the headers, and keeping the specific information apart). As a second choice, with Verpous's (common header at the beginning of each struct, then casting). And as a third choice, with Ian's (similar but more generic).

Often in C you see something like this:
struct Header {
    // ...
}

struct A {
    struct Header header;
    // ...
}

struct B {
    struct Header header;
    // ...
}

As long as you make sure to always put the header at the top, this lets you cast variables of type A* or B* to Header*, and then use this common denominator to both structs. In your case, maybe Header could look like this:
struct Header {
    struct Header *next;
}

Combined with a "cmp" function which receives void*s but knows what type to cast them into and then compares them, you could create a generic sortable linked list.

There is still no justification for making a list consisting of both A and B nodes, even if you put the common parts in a 3rd struct.

@Lundin I didn't mean to imply otherwise. The idea is to build lists of a uniform type, but which are generic. I guess you could shoot yourself in the foot with this idea and build a list of mixed types, but my advice would be to simply... avoid that.

I have used this technique many times and have found it quite useful.  It has the advantage over another answer in that you avoid a lot of ugly casting when using it.  C++ makes this even more natural with inheritance.

He could also keep two (or more) completely separate structs, define the function for receiving ONE of them, cast the actual data into that type/struct (when calling the function), and finally recast it to the specific variant (inside the function). I know, my idea is uglier than yours. Anyway, this will require (a) the header at the beginning and (b) some flag or some logic for identifying the specific struct/type.

I suspect that the actual solution you are looking for is something like this:
typedef enum
{
  I_AM_A,
  I_AM_B,
} what_am_i;

struct node 
{
  tm seconds;
  struct node *next;
  what_am_i id;
  void* data; // points at A or B specific parts
};

That is, use the same struct type but store the specific parts elsewhere. data may be cast to struct a* or struct b* depending on id.

This sound nice and good enough for my needs. The advanced idea of containers seems to be a little bit complicated for myself.
However, when using the void* data how do access data struct of type a? ie struct a {int number; char letter};?
And struct node *knot;
Will knot->data->int=10; work?

And am I right to initialize I use the id value with switch? Like this for a?
knot->next = malloc(sizeof (struct node)); knot->id=I_AM_A;knot->next->data = malloc(sizeof (struct  a));

@Christian Yes and yes (provided knot points to a previously allocated space). And don't forget to check the return of each malloc().

You could embed the sort key and the list as a common sub-structure inside struct a and struct b.
struct timelist {
    tm seconds;
    struct timelist *next;
};

struct a {
    /* some stuff for a */
    struct timelist tl;
    /* some more stuff for a */
};

struct b {
    /* some stuff for b */
    struct timelist tl;
    /* some more stuff for b */
};

Then you can sort it as a list of struct timelist.
At some point, you may need to convert a pointer to a struct timelist to a pointer to the enclosing struct a or struct b. If it could be either, the code needs some way to determine the type of the enclosing type. That could use a special member as suggested in Lundin's answer:
typedef enum
{
    I_AM_A,
    I_AM_B,
} what_am_i;

struct timelist {
    tm seconds;
    what_am_i id;
    struct timelist *next;
};

Then code can switch on the id member value to do different things for different enclosing types:
    switch (tlentry->id) {
    case I_AM_A:
        {
            struct a *aptr = container_of(tlentry, struct a, tl);
            /* do something with aptr */
        }
        break;
    case I_AM_B:
        {
            struct b *bptr = container_of(tlentry, struct b, tl);
            /* do something with bptr */
        }
        break;
    }

In the above, container_of(ptr, type, member) is a macro defined to convert the address of a member to the address of the structure containing the member.  One simple definition of container_of is as follows:
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
    ((type *)((char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member)))

where offsetof is defined by #include <stddef.h>.
(The Linux kernel source has a macro with the same name and function that also does some static error checking but relies on a GCC extension to do so.)
The advantage of using container_of is that it allows the struct timelist to appear anywhere in the enclosing structure rather than being forced to be at the beginning of the enclosing structure.
Brief explanation of what container_of(ptr, type, member) does
For the sake of argument, let us assume that the tl member of struct a is located at an offset of 8 bytes from the start of the struct, then offsetof(struct a, tl) will be 8. For the allocation struct a *aptr = malloc(sizeof(*aptr));, let us assume that *aptr is located at numeric address 1000 (e.g. in a flat address space where addresses linearly map to uintptr_t values, and (uintptr_t)aptr happens to be 1000). After struct timelist *tlentry = &aptr->tl;, *tlentry will be located at numeric address 1008 because tlentry is pointing to the tl member located 8 bytes beyond the start of the containing object *aptr.
The macro expansion container_of(tlentry, struct a, tl) will expand to ((struct a *)((char *)(tlentry) - offsetof(struct a, tl))). Here, (char *)(tlentry) just converts the tlentry pointer value from the original type struct timelist * to char * so that the subsequent pointer arithmetic will be resolved to the individual byte level. The pointer value (char *)tlentry will map to numeric address 1008. As previously determined, offsetof(struct a, tl) will be 8. The pointer value resulting from the subtraction (char *)tlentry - offsetof(struct a, tl) will be be mapped to numeric address 1000 (i.e. 1008 - 8), but its type is still char *. This numeric address 1000 is the address of the struct a object *aptr. Finally, ((struct a *)((char *)(tlentry) - offsetof(struct a, tl))) casts that (char *)(tlentry) - offsetof(struct a, tl) (mapped to numeric address 1000) back to a pointer value of type struct a * that will compare equal to the original aptr.

This is a very good solution (actually, a variant of the solutions already proposed), useful when the common elements are not at the beginning (or at any known position) of each different struct. But I think it may be too complicated for this specific case.

@DiegoFerruchelli It also works around the problem of only being able to inspect the common initial sequence of members of two structures interchangeably when the structures are members of a union.

I guess is the most perfect solution. I have to state this is above my knowledge level to understand. So I will not use it as I will be unable to troubleshoot ;)
Anyways, thumbs up for great advice! Tahnk!

@Christian I suppose I should add a brief explanation of what the container_of macro does!

@Christian You may see this as a generalization of Verpous's idea. Your code will traverse the list using pointers to the nodes called struct timelist, which are similar to Verpous's "headers" but may appear at ANY position into the struct a (or struct b, etc). That is, a given struct timelist may contain ANYTHING above it and/or ANYTHING below it. The macro container_of() is key for accessing the entire struct a (or struct b, etc) "going back" the appropriate number of bytes from the beginning of each struct timelist. The computation is done by offsetof().

Please note that container_of() and offsetof() are macros: the hard work is done by the compiler (not in run time), because the compiler knows the exact size of struct a, b, etc, and the exact position of the timelist inside each one of them. This could also be done in run-time, but you would need to add this extra data somewhere (maybe inside another field of the timelist).
